# How to store images to assets/images folder in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing the client side of an app where image upload and retrieval are needed.I'm not using any server side code now, but for the testing purpose I want to upload image files using a form and store it into the assets/image folder of angular project directory, I couldn't find an example on how to store image to angular's own directory, Most of the examples online use server side code to achieve this. I need a  example to save the image received from the form to angular project's own directory.Thanks in adavance

Comment: Are you expecting to save something to the filesysteem without server side code...?

Comment: @MikeOne Ys,I know it is not possible to access the local file system from directly from angular code... But It is possible to load files stored inside the angular project directory so I'm searching the possibility of  storing the  file to the angular project directory directly from angular component

Comment: I’m sorry, it’s not clear what you want, and you seem to contradict yourself. What exactly do you mean with  “ storing the file to the angular project directory directly from angular component“..? If you need to ‘save’ or ‘store’ something on the filesysteem, you will not be able to do this from code that runs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this piece of code template at **angular**(client) side;

```
<input type="file"title="Select file" name="file"/>

<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="uploadFile()"></button>
```

However you need to have a service at server site to fullfill this file upload request.

For example: **NodeJS**&**Express**
you can use **multer** package as a service to fullfill file upload requests;
Here an example to give an idea;

```
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: UPLOAD_DIR
      filename: file_id;
      }
    });

   const fileMulterUpload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('imageFile');
   const router = express.Router(); 
   router.route('/file_upload_service_url/:id').put(fileMulterUpload,file.fileOnSaved);
```